# Creating many_to_many relations between objects outside of Django to add fake data in db

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using the faker library to ad data to a database.

I have 2 models Entity and Item with a many to many relationship between them.
I want to create a random relation between Item and Entity.

```
item_list = Item.objects.all()

for item in item_list:
            item.entities = Entity.objects.order_by('?')[0]
```

entities is the M2M that exist in the Item Model;

```
class Item(models.Model)

 entities = models.ManyToManyField(Entity, related_name='items')
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use categories.set() instead.
```

So I tried

```
item.entity_set = Entity.objects.order_by('?')[0]
item.save()
```

No error, but no relation is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use method `add` without `save`

```
item.entities.add(Entity.objects.order_by('?')[0])
```

read more [many_to_many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: how do I check if a many to many exist; using if item.entity always return true ?